# How to pass parameters from a modal viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have two viewcontrollers.  Here is the second one:

```
UIViewController *modal = [[ModalViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Second modal window:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

How do I pass parameters from a modal view controller?

Comment: Can you please explain your question more? You want to pass parameters from one view controller to another?

Comment: "The first is the second"...? So they're they're pointing to the same object? You should edit this question: it's not clear from what to what you want to pass parameters, even the sentences are hard to read (is there a dot after 4th word or that's the continuation of the sentence..?). Passing parameters anyway is really a basic task and you should read a tutorial firstly, which will teach you such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to make / tell the presenting controller to dismiss the modal view controller ***from*** the modal view controller?

I gather that being the reason why you thought of passing `self` as "parameter" to the modal view controller, so that it could reference it and make it dismiss the `ModalViewController` through the use of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` as you mentioned?

If so, you could make use of protocol:

In your modal view controller's header file (`.h`), declare:

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerProtocol

@require
 - (void)dismiss;
@end
@interface ModalViewController
```

In your presented controller, which is `ModalViewController` in your case, declare the following in `.h`:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) id<ModalViewControllerProtocol>myDelegate;
```

and make your presenting controller so that it adopts to the protocol:

```
@interface presentingViewController <ModalViewControllerProtocol>
```

And:

```
ModalViewController *modal = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
modal.myDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When your modal view controller is presented and you would like to tell your presenting controller to dismiss it, you could do:

```
[self.myDelegate dismiss];
```

And finally implement the `dismiss` method in your presenting view controller:

```
- (void)dismiss
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

One could also forget about all of the aforementioned and simply call the following in the presented view controller (which, in your case, the `ModalViewController`):

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But there are cases that `self.presentingViewController` is not returning the same controller that presented the modal view controller. Hence, using the protocol method would assure that we would like the same presenting view controller to dismiss the presented controller.

---

Comment: Thank you. That's what I had.
Unfortunately I have not got to that point to this in my book. You helped me a lot. Sorry for my English. While he is not a high level.

Comment: I have a modal window contains filters. Clicking on the filtered data should enter the main view

Comment: Now I use a data Singleton. It is true I am doing?

Comment: @imiroslav It’s ok. No need to apologize. With regards to your last 2 comments: we’d need a lot more information, in order to answer, namely, on your view hierarchy (2nd comment) and the data structure (3rd comment), in order to know whether it warrants the use of the singleton pattern. If you have an abstract view hierarchy, which would then be too abstract and difficult to describe, you could post screenshots or links thereof. Given all that, posting in 2 separate questions would be helpful, because you would have more room to describe and the answerers, more space to answer. Good luck!